# Swift - Alamofire parse long JSON response

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've getting an response from Alamofire .POST like a long JSON, and it look like this:

```
 "name_srname": "AAA BBB",
        "playerData": {
            "userData": {
                "waypointNumber": null,
                "longitude": 33.333,
                "latitude": 33.333,
                "address": {
                    "street": "aaa",
                    "city": "aaaa",
                    "country": "EN",
                    "zipCode": "00-00"
                },
                "dataTracker": null
            },
            "userDetails": {
                "level": 1,
                "exp_amount": 21.161993612,
                "points_amount": 90,
                "items": {
                    "armor": "aa",
                    "weapon": "aa",
                    "ring": "aa",
                    "helmet": "aa"
                },
                "rawData": null,
                "userCreateDate": "2021-03-10T12:00:00",
                "userLastActivity": "2021-03-10T12:00:00",
                "isActive": null
            },
            "lastWaypoint": [
                {
                    "type": null,
                    "waypointNumber": "01",
                    "longitude": 33.333,
                    "latitude": 33.333,
                    "address": {
                        "street": "aa",
                        "city": "aa",
                        "country": "aa",
                        "zipCode": "00-00"
                    },
                    "addressRaw": "",
                    "lastWaypointCreate": "2021-03-10T07:00:00",
                    "lastWaypointBegin": "2021-03-10T07:00:00",
                    "inGeofenceRange": null
                }
            ],
            "GuildName": "Iaaaa",
            "rankName": "aaaa",
            "progress": 93,
            "isReady": true,
            "timeJoin": "2021-03-10T11:42:00.673"
```

Ok now when we know what we got just create a new Class to handle it, like in Android.

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - ClassElement
class ClassElement: Codable {
    let nameSrname: String
    let playerData: PlayerData

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case nameSrname
        case playerData
    }

    init(nameSrname: String, playerData: PlayerData) {
        self.nameSrname = nameSrname
        self.playerData = playerData
    }
}

//
// To read values from URLs:
//
//   let task = URLSession.shared.playerDataTask(with: url) { playerData, response, error in
//     if let playerData = playerData {
//       ...
//     }
//   }
//   task.resume()

// MARK: - PlayerData
class PlayerData: Codable {
    let userData: UserData
    let userDetails: UserDetails
    let lastWaypoint: [LastWaypoint]
    let guildName, rankName: String
    let progress: Int
    let isReady: Bool
    let timeJoin: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userData, userDetails, lastWaypoint
        case guildName
        case rankName, progress, isReady, timeJoin
    }

    init(userData: UserData, userDetails: UserDetails, lastWaypoint: [LastWaypoint], guildName: String, rankName: String, progress: Int, isReady: Bool, timeJoin: String) {
        self.userData = userData
        self.userDetails = userDetails
        self.lastWaypoint = lastWaypoint
        self.guildName = guildName
        self.rankName = rankName
        self.progress = progress
        self.isReady = isReady
        self.timeJoin = timeJoin
    }
}

//
// To read values from URLs:
//
//   let task = URLSession.shared.lastWaypointTask(with: url) { lastWaypoint, response, error in
//     if let lastWaypoint = lastWaypoint {
//       ...
//     }
//   }
//   task.resume()

// MARK: - LastWaypoint
class LastWaypoint: Codable {
    let type: JSONNull?
    let waypointNumber: String
    let longitude, latitude: Double
    let address: Address
    let addressRaw, lastWaypointCreate, lastWaypointBegin: String
    let inGeofenceRange: JSONNull?

    init(type: JSONNull?, waypointNumber: String, longitude: Double, latitude: Double, address: Address, addressRaw: String, lastWaypointCreate: String, lastWaypointBegin: String, inGeofenceRange: JSONNull?) {
        self.type = type
        self.waypointNumber = waypointNumber
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.address = address
        self.addressRaw = addressRaw
        self.lastWaypointCreate = lastWaypointCreate
        self.lastWaypointBegin = lastWaypointBegin
        self.inGeofenceRange = inGeofenceRange
    }
}

//
// To read values from URLs:
//
//   let task = URLSession.shared.addressTask(with: url) { address, response, error in
//     if let address = address {
//       ...
//     }
//   }
//   task.resume()

// MARK: - Address
class Address: Codable {
    let street, city, country, zipCode: String

    init(street: String, city: String, country: String, zipCode: String) {
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.country = country
        self.zipCode = zipCode
    }
}

//
// To read values from URLs:
//
//   let task = URLSession.shared.userDataTask(with: url) { userData, response, error in
//     if let userData = userData {
//       ...
//     }
//   }
//   task.resume()

// MARK: - UserData
class UserData: Codable {
    let waypointNumber: JSONNull?
    let longitude: Double
    let latitude: Int
    let address: Address
    let dataTracker: JSONNull?

    init(waypointNumber: JSONNull?, longitude: Double, latitude: Int, address: Address, dataTracker: JSONNull?) {
        self.waypointNumber = waypointNumber
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.address = address
        self.dataTracker = dataTracker
    }
}

//
// To read values from URLs:
//
//   let task = URLSession.shared.userDetailsTask(with: url) { userDetails, response, error in
//     if let userDetails = userDetails {
//       ...
//     }
//   }
//   task.resume()

// MARK: - UserDetails
class UserDetails: Codable {
    let level: Int
    let expAmount: Double
    let pointsAmount: Int
    let items: Items
    let rawData: JSONNull?
    let userCreateDate, userLastActivity: String
    let isActive: JSONNull?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case level
        case expAmount
        case pointsAmount
        case items, rawData, userCreateDate, userLastActivity, isActive
    }

    init(level: Int, expAmount: Double, pointsAmount: Int, items: Items, rawData: JSONNull?, userCreateDate: String, userLastActivity: String, isActive: JSONNull?) {
        self.level = level
        self.expAmount = expAmount
        self.pointsAmount = pointsAmount
        self.items = items
        self.rawData = rawData
        self.userCreateDate = userCreateDate
        self.userLastActivity = userLastActivity
        self.isActive = isActive
    }
}

//
// To read values from URLs:
//
//   let task = URLSession.shared.itemsTask(with: url) { items, response, error in
//     if let items = items {
//       ...
//     }
//   }
//   task.resume()

// MARK: - Items
class Items: Codable {
    let armor, weapon, ring, helmet: String

    init(armor: String, weapon: String, ring: String, helmet: String) {
        self.armor = armor
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.ring = ring
        self.helmet = helmet
    }
}

typealias Class = [ClassElement]

// MARK: - Helper functions for creating encoders and decoders

func newJSONDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return decoder
}

func newJSONEncoder() -> JSONEncoder {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return encoder
}

// MARK: - URLSession response handlers

extension URLSession {
    fileprivate func codableTask<T: Codable>(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (T?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        return self.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completionHandler(nil, response, error)
                return
            }
            completionHandler(try? newJSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data), response, nil)
        }
    }

    func classTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Class?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        return self.codableTask(with: url, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

And in the next point I want to handle it with Alamofire, and I've a code like:

```
        AF.request("URL", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                //print(response)
                
                var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
                if (statusCode != 200){
                    self.view.makeToast("Something went wrong...");
                } else{
                   // self.view.makeToast("It's ok");
                    if let classResponse = response.data {
                        do {
                            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ClassElement.self, from: classResponse)
                            print(response)
                        } catch {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                         }
                    
                }
            }
```

And im getting error like "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." Im new in Swift so im trying to use it like in a Android but I think I missunderstand something... Can someone help me? I just want to get every value from this response for example the response.playerData.userData.waypointNumber but I don't know how to receive it.

Comment: "I just want to get every value from this response"  You have skipped 'GuildName' over 'playerData,' right?

Comment: Hello, why do you mean „skipped”? I want to get any value from this json to save it to the database.

Comment: So can someone help me? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close my old question.
The problem why im getting the error was the fact, im getting the json list so my json parser will look like:

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([ClassElement].self, from: classResponse)
```